# Create Oracle Table Function

Tags: oracle, function

I have what I thought is a rather simple question, but I don't get the syntax right. I want to define a TABLE function so that I can use it like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_fct('20000101', '20991231'));
```

My current function looks like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_fct(p_FROM_DATE IN VARCHAR2, p_UNTIL_DATE IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN IMP_EMPL_DATA%ROWTYPE PIPELINED
AS
    TYPE CurTyp IS REF CURSOR RETURN IMP_EMPL_DATA%ROWTYPE;
    rc CurTyp;

    CURSOR data IS SELECT *
        FROM IMP_EMPL_DATA IPED
        WHERE (IPED.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
        AND IPED.CREATEDATE BETWEEN to_date(p_FROM_DATE, 'yyyymmdd') AND to_date(p_UNTIL_DATE, 'yyyymmdd');

BEGIN
    FOR rc IN data LOOP
        PIPE ROW (rc);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I've found several examples where they define a new record and table type. In my example, I'm perfectly fine to use the (existing) table rowtype.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `TABLE` function which returns a record.(`RETURN IMP_EMPL_DATA%ROWTYPE`).

You should create an `OBJECT` and it's table `TYPE`  in the schema and only then you may be able to use it.

```
CREATE
    OR replace type IMP_EMPL_DATA_OBJ AS OBJECT (
    col1 varchar2(10)
    ,col2 INT
    ,col3 DATE
    );  -- Include all columns of table IMP_EMPL_DATA

CREATE
    OR replace type 
IMP_EMPL_DATA_OBJ_TAB AS TABLE OF IMP_EMPL_DATA_OBJ;
```

Now, the function should return the collection type

```
RETURN IMP_EMPL_DATA_OBJ_TAB PIPELINED AS ..
```

Comment: Is it possible to leverage the table or table row type somehow, or do I really need to copy the definition to define the new type? In the my case both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be like this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE IMP_EMPL_DATA_REC AS OBJECT ( 
    STATUS VARCHAR2(15),
    CREATEDATE DATE,
    ...);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE IMP_EMPL_DATA_TABLE AS TABLE OF IMP_EMPL_DATA_REC;




CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_fct(p_FROM_DATE IN VARCHAR2, p_UNTIL_DATE IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN IMP_EMPL_DATA_TABLE PIPELINED
AS
    rec IMP_EMPL_DATA_REC;

    CURSOR data IS 
    SELECT *
    FROM IMP_EMPL_DATA IPED
    WHERE (IPED.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
       AND IPED.CREATEDATE BETWEEN to_date(p_FROM_DATE, 'yyyymmdd') AND to_date(p_UNTIL_DATE, 'yyyymmdd');

BEGIN
    FOR rc IN data LOOP
        rec := IMP_EMPL_DATA_REC(rc.STATUS, rc.CREATEDATE, ...);
        PIPE ROW(rec);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Since my response type is equal to the table record type, I thought I can avoid all the boilerplate of creating the type and creating the return object with the actual values. But rather leverage the existing table definition

Comment: But for a plain select you would not need a PIPELINED function. Maybe it would be better to return a RefCursor.